# How can I find the closed form of this recursive relationship: $a_{n}=(a_{n-1})^2+a_{n-1},a_{0}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

This comes up in OEIS as [A007018](http://oeis.org/A007018). However the recursive form is useless to me, I need the closed form. I've been trying for several hours and I simply come up empty. Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the explicit form? The recursive form looks pretty explicit. Do you mean the closed form to evaluate $a_n$  for any $n$?

Comment: The fact that the only closed form given in the OEIS entry is $a(n) = \left\lfloor c^{2^n}\right\rfloor$, where $c=1.597910218031873178338070118157\ldots$, suggests that you won’t do any better than this.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Note that $c$ was probably computed by evaluating the sequence recursively up to some $n$. (Similar to the "closed form" for the Fibonacci sequence that requires finding the Golden Ratio to arbitrary precision...)

Comment: @Newb: Yes, after showing that there is a closed expression of that form.

Comment: @Newb, Yes, my bad, thank you! I'm looking for something like Brian M. Scott posted, but I don't know how I would ever arrive at that solution on my own without a computer.

Comment: Knuth's comment in OEIS that "*Using the methods of Aho and Sloane, Fibonacci Quarterly 11 (1973), 429-437, it is easy to show that $a_n$ is the integer just a tiny bit below the real number $\theta^{2^n}-\frac12$, where $\theta \approx 1.597910218$ is the exponential of the rapidly convergent series $\ln\frac32+\sum_{n \ge 0} \ln(1+(2a_n+1)^{-2})$*" gives you a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are just two (diagonalized monic) versions that give nice closed forms:
$$ x_n = x_{n-1}^2 $$
gives $$ x_n = x_0^{\left( 2^n \right) }.  $$
The other, used by Lucas, is
$$ x_n = x_{n-1}^2 - 2; \; \; \; \;  x_0 > 2. $$ 
This time we find $A > 1,$ with $AB = 1$ and $A + B = x_0.$
Then
$$ x_n = A^{\left( 2^n \right) } + B^{\left( 2^n \right) }.  $$

That is all the nice ones. For the others, taking logarithm of both sides shows that there is a limit which is the number $c$ from OEIS, but we can only estimate $c$ by calculating many terms of the sequence itself.

With your sequence, taking $$ a_n = b_n - \frac{1}{2} $$
gives
$$  b_n = b_{n-1}^2 +  \frac{1}{4} $$ 
so you are out of luck as far as closed form answers. With this much, not difficult to prove that
$$  \frac{\log b_n}{2^n}  $$ has a limit as $n \rightarrow \infty,$ call it $w,$ then the number $c = e^w.$